# Need to move a file having double digit numeric values in bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I want to move few files that have numeric values as part of filename. For example pattern 'ABC123_10_abc.txt' to a destination location as 'ABC123_abc.txt '

current command used:

```
mv $prefix_[0-9]_$suffix $prefix_$suffix;
```

But the above is not working for double digits. whereas if i put `*[0-9]` it is creating issue in identifying unique filename, so please suggest

Comment: So what is the value of `prefix` and `suffix`?

Comment: Here $prefix=ABC123 and $suffix=abc.txt that will remain in the new file name but needs to remove numeric value in between them.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged as *bash*, so I assume scripting is ok. This should help:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for file; do
    if [[ "${file}" =~ ^(.+)_[0-9]+_(.+)$ ]]; then
        prefix="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
        suffix="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
        mv -v "${file}" "${prefix}_${suffix}"
    else
        echo "File '${file}' does not match regex, skipping"
    fi
done
```

Save this script as e.g. `renamer.sh`, make it executable and run it with the files to rename provided as arguments, e.g. `./renamer.sh *.txt`.

Each filename is matched against regular expression `^(.+)_[0-9]+_(.+)$` which dissects the filename into `prefix` and `suffix` per your description. The file is then renamed to `${prefix}_${suffix}`. Works for any number of digits regarding the `_xx_` part.

---

Note that this is based on the little information you provided. If that's not what you're looking for, please clarify your question by adding further details.

Comment: can you help me with the regex that can detect double digit numeric values in filename. currently i am using below: 
 mv $prefix_[0-9]_$suffix $prefix_$suffix; where prefix and suffix are both part of the filename and numeric values are added to store duplicate files. This command runs fine when numeric value is within the range of 1-9 but the moment it is 10 this command fails to remove the numeric portion from the filename.

Comment: @KTS: you're are confusing a few things here. In the command `mv $prefix_[0-9]_$suffix $prefix_$suffix`, the `$prefix_[0-9]_$suffix $prefix_$suffix` part is **not** a regular expression. Bash does not support regular expressions in this fashion. Have you read my answer? It provides a solution.

Comment: @KTS: if you're dealing with **excatly** to digits, you might be able to use `mv $prefix_[0-9][0-9]_$suffix $prefix_$suffix`, but I somewhat doubt that this is really what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried the option mv $prefix_[0-9][0-9]_$suffix $prefix_$suffix already but it dint work.

Comment: @KTS: I see. Have you also tried the script from my answer?

Comment: yeah i tried and it is not working.

Comment: Is there a way this move command can accomodate double digits in move command?

Comment: @KTS: you mean directly within this one `mv` command? None that I can't think of.